# grails enum type in domain class

Tags: java, grails, enums

I use grails 1.3.2 and hbase..

I have domain class, one of which fields is in enum type:

```
class MyDomainClass{

     MyEnum enumVal

        //....

}

public enum MyEnum {

    val1("val1"),
    val2("val2")

   final String value
   MyEnum (String value) {
      this.value = value
    }
   String toString() { value }
   String getKey() { name() }
}


<g:form action="create">
   <g:select name="enumVal" from="${MyEnum ?.values()}" optionKey="key" />
   <g:submitButton name="createOb" value="CreateOb"/>
</g:form>
```

"create" action have to save selected value in db.

When I submit I get exception:

```
Cannot cast object 'val1' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'myPack.MyEnum '
```

Is there any way to save enum value as a String?

Comment: This may be an hbase issue because I have code like this all over the place and it works fine, but I'm using plain old MySQL.

Comment: I can get enum values, but I can not save it in db..

Answer (score 1):

1. The space after "`MyEnum`" in GSP and error message makes me doubt, can you remove it from GSP?
2. You don't need ?, as `MyEnum` class should always be there.
3. I believe you don't need `optionKey`, especially if you have overridden `MyEnum.toString()`.
4. We write `select`s from enum this way:

   <g:select from="${SomeEnum.values()*.toFriendlyString()}"
   keys="${SomeEnum.values()*.name()}"
   value="${xxxInstance.field.name()}" ...
   />

where toFriendlyString() is our Enum's method that returns user-readable String representation.

Comment: Victor thank you for replying...I have changed view, but i got exception: Exception Message: No signature of method: myPack.MyEnum.toFriendlyString() is applicable for argument types: () values: []                                                 Caused by: Error executing tag <g:form>: Error evaluating expression [MyEnum.values()*.toFriendlyString()] on line [15]: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:

Comment: Sorry. That's a method we added ourselves, it returns localized string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a data-type conversion issue. You may try:

```
def domainObject = new MyDomainClass()
def enumValue = myPack.MyEnum.valueOf(params.enumVal) // This is the conversion.
```

After that, assign your domain object with the new `enumValue`.